# Render Mapbox tiles with Mapzen's Tangram

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, mapbox, mapzen, tangram

We've built a few projects using Mapzen's vector tiles and rendering them through Tangram. However, now that Mapzen is shutting down, we need to use other tile servers (we would like to maintain the rendering through Tangram, since we've put some work into getting the styles right).
Is there any way of rendering the tiles provided by Mapbox `http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.mapbox-streets-v7/{z}/{x}/{y}.mvt` using Tangram and their `.yaml` files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tangram handles mapbox or other .mvt tiles fine.  You will have to create/edit/find a new scene file though, the schema is different.  I used mapbox studio to make a style then ran it through this converter: https://github.com/ac87/jsontoyaml

I needed to remove the 'layer' filters from the json style and then some editing on the output but it worked fairly well.

I am now trying out openmaptiles.org tiles, their licensing is much more straightforward (imo).  You could start with this scene file: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/petrsloup/27ee74e2cdebc7ac72129da3a89a440f/raw/19385aae40b9d0ba0a6c0ef1c3afe87f2743d54d/gistfile1.txt

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. I did manage to get Mapbox tiles working with Tangram, although, as you say, I had to heavily edit the scene file. In the end, I got everything except for the labels to work properly (multiple labels for the same feature appeared). The key to understanding the schema was here: https://www.mapbox.com/studio/tilesets/mapbox.mapbox-streets-v7/

I'll try the openmaptiles.org now. Thanks!

Comment: move_into_tile: false on the text draw blocks will help somewhat with the labels but the main cause is that mapbox tiles are buffered and mapzen tiles are not.

Comment: If anyone in the future has a similar question, we are working on a utility for this purpose: https://github.com/stadiamaps/cartogrify. You are still responsible for schema conversions, but should help with the rest.